# Spresenseでスピーカーを使う方法

Tags: spresense

Spresenseでダイナミックスピーカーを使って音を鳴らしたいのですが，Arduinoのようにアナログピンに刺しても音が鳴りませんでした．デジタル端子として使用できないとのことなので，なるほどとは思いました．
では，どこに刺したらスピーカーを使用することができるのでしょうか．

Answer (score 0):

その音を鳴らすというプログラムが、どこのピンにどう言う風にして鳴らすのを想定しているのか、によりつなぐピン／回路が変わってきます。

ってことで、その鳴らすプログラムがどういうコードになっているのか、を読むことです。

Answer (score 0):

他のコメントにあるとおり、プログラムで出力しているポートとあっていますかね。

やりたいイメージとあっているかわかりませんが、もしダイナミックスピーカーなどをつないで関数操作で鳴らすのであれば、スピーカの端子をGND端子とPWM出力可能なD<番号>のデジタルポート端子に接続して、Arduinoのtone()やanalogWrite()関数に接続したピン番号を引数に指定すれば実現できると思います。

spresense PWMの出力ポートについて：
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_analogwrite